# Implicit type casts in expressions with bit shifts

Tags: c++, 64-bit

In the code below, **why** 1-byte `anUChar` is automatically converted into 4 bytes to produce the desired result 0x300 (instead of 0x0 if `anUChar` would remain 1 byte in size):

```
unsigned char anUChar = 0xc0; // only the two most significant bits are set
int anInt = anUChar << 2; // 0x300 (correct)
```

**But** in this code, aimed at a 64-bit result, no automatic conversion into 8 bytes happens:

```
unsigned int anUInt = 0xc0000000; // only the two most significant bits are set
long long aLongLong = anUInt << 2; // 0x0 (wrong, means no conversion occurred)
```

And only placing an explicit type cast works:

```
unsigned int anUInt = 0xc0000000;
long long aLongLong = (long long)anUInt << 2; // 0x300000000 (correct)
```

And most importantly, **would** this behavior be the same in a program that targets 64-bit machines?

By the way, which of the two is most right and portable: `(type)var << 1` or `((type)var) << 1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char` always gets promoted to `int` during arithmetic. I think this is specified behavior in the C standard.

However, `int` is not automatically promoted to `long long`.

Under [some situations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke55d167.aspx), some compilers (Visual Studio) will actually warn you about this if you try to left-shift a smaller integer and store it into a larger one.

> By the way, which of the two is most right and portable: `(type)var <<
>   1` or `((type)var) << 1`?

Both are fine and portable. Though I prefer the first one since it's shorter. Casting has higher precedence than shift.

Comment: Thanks. However I compiled the second piece of code in my question with VC++ 9.0 at the highest warning level 4 and no warnings were produced.

Comment: I just remembered  this. It applies only in x64 if the value is used as a pointer offset. Thanks for pointing tha out. I'll fix my answer when I get back to a computer. (on iPhone right now)

Comment: @Naveen: I just fixed my answer. The warning that Visual Studio will sometimes emit is this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke55d167.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Shorter integral types are promoted to an `int` type for bitshift operations. This has nothing to do with the type to which you *assign* the result of the shift.

On 64-bit machines, your second piece of code would be equally problematic since the int types are usually also 32 bit wide. (Between x86 and x64, `long long int` is typically always 64 and `int` 32 bits, only `long int` depends on the platform.)

(In the spirit of C++, I would write the conversion as `(unsigned long long int)(anUInt) << 2`, evocative of the conversion-constructor syntax. The first set of parentheses is purely because the type name consists of several tokens.)

I would also prefer to do bitshifting exclusively on *unsigned types*, because only unsigned types can be considered equivalent (in terms of *values*) to their own bit pattern value.

Comment: @Oli: You're right, let me edit! I was thinking of `long int`.

Answer (score 2):

Conversion *does* happen.  The problem is the result of the expression `anUInt << 2` is an `unsigned int` because `anUInt` is an `unsigned int`.

Casting `anUInt` to a `long long` (actually, this is conversion in this particular case) is the correct thing to do.

Neither `(type)var << 1` or `((type)var) << 1` is more correct or portable because operator precedence is strictly defined by the Standard.  However, the latter is probably *better* because it's easier to understand to humans looking at the code casually.  Others may disagree with this assertion.

EDIT:

Note that in your first example:

```
unsigned char anUChar = 0xc0; 
int anInt = anUChar << 2;
```

...the result of the expression `anUChar << 2` is not an `unsigned char` as you might expect, but an `int` because of Integral Promotion.

The operands of `operator<<` are integral or enumeration type (See Standard 5.8/1). When a binary operator that expects operands of arithmetic or enumeration type is called, the compiler attempts to convert both operands to the same type, so that the expression may yield a common type.  In this case, integral promotion is performed on both operands (5/9).  When an `unsigned char` takes part in integral promotion, it will be converted to an `int` if your platform can accomodate all possible values of `unsigned char` in an `int`, else it will be converted to an `unsigned int` (4.5/1).

Comment: You might want to touch on why the char got converted then, since your post accidentally implies that it shouldn't have.

Comment: `the result of the expression anUInt << 2 is an unsigned int because anUInt is an unsigned int.`  This implies: `the result of the expression anUChar << 2 is an unsigned char because anUChar is an unsigned char.`

Answer (score 1):

Because of *integer promotions*.  For most operators (e.g. `<<`), `char` operands are promoted to `int` first.

This has nothing to do with where the result of the calculation is going.  In other words, the fact that your second example assigns to a `long long` does not affect the promotion of the operands.